# Replaced a Heat/Light/Vent with a vent only. There does not seem to be a hot wire:

Tags: wiring, vent

The three gang box previously had a HLV combined switch plus a switch that operated a separate light.  Stupidly, I removed and discarded the switches and units (light and HLV) without studying the connections.  The gang box now has 2) 12/2 and 1) 12/3 romex.  I want to connect two independent lights and a vent.   When testing I am not finding a hot connection.   In the ceiling one 12/2 is connected to the Broan vent with a black/white and ground.   The other 12/2 goes to one light and the 12/3 is connected to the other light with the red wire capped off.  What am I missing?

Comment: Carefully spread all the wires so they're not touching, pull the wire nuts/electrical tape off the ends to expose them, then turn the power on. Using your multimeter, find out where the power is coming into the system, then shut it back off at the breaker. There's gotta be a hot in there somewhere...